# Linux enable pca9685 in sysfs

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

I would like to enable a `PCA9685` as a `PWM` in `/sys/class/pwm/`.

The Platform is a `Raspberry Pi 2` and the chip is connected to `/dev/i2c-1`.

I find the chip with `i2c-detect`, but i don't know how do I enable this driver:
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/pwm/pwm-pca9685.c.
I also found this but it doesn't tell me how to `configure sysfs` to use this driver: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/pwm.txt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable `CONFIG_PWM_PCA9685` in your `.config` file of your `linux-kernel`. By default, `CONFIG_PWM_PCA9685 is not set` and you need to enable it as `CONFIG_PWM_PCA9685=y`if you want to build it as a part of kernel image, or as `CONFIG_PWM_PCA9685=m`if you want to build it as a `LKM`.

Also make sure that `CONFIG_SYSFS` is `enabled` in your `.config`. If `CONFIG_SYSFS` is enabled in your kernel configuration, a simple `sysfs` interface is provided to use the `PWMs` from userspace. It is exposed at `/sys/class/pwm/`. Each probed `PWM controller/chip` will be exported as `pwmchipN`, where `N` is the base of the `PWM chip`.

Comment: Besides above one should enable the driver in device tree (either DTS, or ACPI, or built-in device properties / platform data).